# How do I make a list from ifconfig -a?

Tags: bash, shell, ifconfig

Hello I'm trying to use ifconfig -a to list out all interfaces and then further make it into a menu where you can select which interface to use. Right now I have `ifconfig -a | sed 's/[ \t].*//;/^$/d' | nl -n ln -w 6`
This displays

1       eth0:

2       lo:

3       wlan0:

I want to be able to press 1 or 2 or 3 and then have it assign the option's corresponding interface name to a variable, lets say $networkname. So when echo "${networkname}" is run it only displays `eth0` or `wlan0` or `lo`

Comment: ifconfig is obsolete. You should be using ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /sys/class/net || exit 1

select int in *; do break; done
echo "$int"
```